# Temporary or memory table?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm developing account system for android and i'm stuck with 'Receipt' window in which the user select the way of payment: Cash, Credit C....

My issue is with cheques (checks) where the user enter the details of the every cheques (maybe one, two, ..):

```
Value date  Ch.No  account    Bank   Amount
--------------------------------------------
15/10/2014 | 1234 |  65654 |   10  |  2400 
15/11/2014 | 1234 |  65654 |   10  |  1400
15/12/2014 | 1234 |  65654 |   10  |  1500
```

How can I temporary save these data, because maybe user want to edit/delete before issuing the Receipt? and sending the data to server side.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `Map<Integer, Cheque> chequeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Cheque>(); chequeMap.put(chequeNumber, new Cheque(chequeNumber, date, accountNumber, bank, amount);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to store them in memory for use later, you could use a `HashMap` with the cheque number being your key. Something like:

```
Map<Integer, Cheque> chequeMap = new HashMap<Integer, Cheque>();
chequeMap.put(chequeNumber, 
                new Cheque(chequeNumber, date, accountNumber, bank, amount);
```

Then later to get them, you'd do something like:

```
Cheque someCheque = chequeMap.get(chequeNumber);
```

Or to get them all out, like when you go to store them in your database or print them, etc... you'd do something like:

```
for (Cheque cheque : chequeMap.values()) {
    // do stuff here with your cheuqe objects
}
```